# Proving $\forall x, |x| \leq 2 => |x^3 - 7x + 3| \leq 25 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

$\forall x, |x| \leq 2 => |x^3 - 7x + 3| \leq 25 $

Suppose $ |x| \leq 2 $, then we can deduce that $ |x - 2| \leq 0$.

But even if I apply that deduced stuff in the the triangle inequality,
I'm not sure how I will bring the $x^3$ part of the proof. Any idea on
how to proceed ?

Comment: You can't deduce $|x-2|\leq 0$. Consider for instance $x=-2$.

Comment: Apply the triangle inequality twice, i.e. so you have three terms (one for each of $x^3$, $-7x$ and $3$)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

$$|x^3 - 7x + 3|$$

applying the triangle inequality produces

$$|x^3 - 7x + 3|\le |x^3| + |7x| + |3|=|x^3| + 7|x| + 3$$
now since $|x|\le 2$ we have
$$|x^3|\le 8$$
$$7|x|\le 14$$
so that
$$|x^3| + 7|x| + 3\le 8 + 14 + 3 = 25$$
therefore we may conclude
$$|x^3 - 7x + 3|\le 25$$

Answer (score 0):

It it $$|x^3-7x+3|\le |x|^3+7|x|+3\le 8+14+3=25$$ if $|x|\le 2$